# What makes this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How to help a friend that is suddenly socially withdrawn?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-to-help-a-friend-that-is-suddenly-socially-withdrawn)

First, this is not about dealing with suicidal people. Socially withdrawal might be a symptom of depression, but not all social withdrawal is caused by depression. Dealing with people suffering with either one is already considered off topic in this site.

Second, I've edited the question to limit dealing with friend that suddenly withdraw, but still allow occasional meeting with close friends and relatives, but refuse going out or participate in social activity.

Can you give me insight what can I improve from my answer?

Comment: I think your edit was good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Being withdrawn" is very vague. Without a more specific problem statement, it would take a shelf of books to even begin to address the entire spectrum of problems your friend may be having.

Stack Exchange Q&A is generally designed to answer very specific questions that can be answered definitively in the space of a post. @Catija suggested in the comments that your question should at least narrow down to a more specific problem set. You might, for example, re-focus your question to how to bring a friend back into your friendship circle — that's assuming this is what you are actually asking.

As of now, folks here can only *guess* what information might help you specifically. That is why it is closed as *too broad.*

Comment: `But this is about someone who is usually has no issue with social life, then suddenly decided to refuse any social activity, including his/her close friends.` Is this not enough to define the scope of social withdrawn we are talking about?

Comment: Catija's comment : `But we need you to pick one.` I has since edited the question immediately after the comment, and narrowed it to friends who do not refuse close relatives and friends, and excluding the one who totally refuse outside world - I decided this might be too close to possibility of suicidal tendency.